# Java/Scala Nashorn disable exit()?

Tags: java, scala

Hello is there a way to disable Nashorn's exit function in Java?

Currently if I have a script engine (Scala):

```
val engine = new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine("-strict", "--no-java", "--no-syntax-extensions")
```

I could still run the following:

```
engine.eval("exit(1);");
```

I mean it's javascript so I could have a eval before with the following:

```
engine.eval("exit = undefined");
```

However I thought that I could make it more safe with java code, is there any way of making the Nashorn Script Engine more strict that such Safetyness is there by default?

Comment: You can use the Bindings and bindings.remove("exit"); but that is pretty much the same solution you came up with.

Comment: Is exit the only unsafe function or did I miss others?

Comment: Depends on how strict you are in evaluating security. load() or loadWithNewGlobal() could be considered unsafe in most use cases where users may provide script fragments. You also have an alias to exit() with the quit() function. Reflection / access to Java classes can be limited by configuring a ClassFilter, using a security manager or configuring the engine with the  "--no-java" flag (JJS)

Comment: @AxelFaust as in my example I already have a "--no-java" flag, however it still fells insecure.

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt I missed that parameter. But installing a security manager still remains an option. Scripts executed from String via eval() will be considered insecure by default and have the strictest Java security policy applied while all scripts you load from file / URL can be secured via a normal policy file (as far as security manager framework allows). That should also allow you to define what / if scripts can be loaded via load() / loadWithNewGlobal()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of others I found two ways:

either like @matt suggested:

```
bindings.remove("exit");
```

or via

```
engine.eval("exit = undefined");
```